# SQL> CONNECT / as SYSDBA ERROR: ORA-24314: service handle not initialized

Tags: oracle

I just installed Oracle 9i in my PC. For initial login I'm using following to unlock user.

```
Connect SQLPLUS using /nolog
```

Then when I use following command in SQLPLUS

```
SQL> CONNECT / as SYSDBA
```

I'm getting following error

> ERROR: ORA-24314: service handle not initialized

Can anyone suggest where things are not going right?

Also I've noticed that SQLPLUS is not working from windows command prompt. I'm using windows 8.1 and oracle 9i (9.0.1.0.1)

Answer (score 0):

Did you .oraenv to your database?

```
cat /etc/oratab
```

to get the dbname (if not already known).

edit: Also why not just issue:

```
 sqlplus / as sysdba
```

?